# How To Change the Color and Font Of Labels of Bar Chart Using ChartistJs Library with ReactJs

Tags: reactjs, charts, bar-chart, chartist.js, react-chartist

I am working with React-Js Application and using ChartistJs Library to show the Charts.
I am trying to change the color and Font of Lables in Bar Chart but unable to find any options to achieve that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can do something like this in your CSS file:

```css
.ct-label {
    color: red;
    font-size: 15px;
    font-family: "Lucida Sans Unicode", "Lucida Grande", sans-serif;
}
```

I hope it helps.